# Firestore security rule using reference to another document

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to base a security rule on a reference to another object.

I have a collection of users and collection of roles. A user object has a field called "role" that is a reference to a particular document in the roles collection.

```
users
  id
  name
  role <-- reference to particular role

roles
  id
  name
  isSuperUser
```

The goal here is to allow a user with a particular role (the role with isSuperUser == true) to edit any other role or it's sub-collections;

Here are my rules that I would have thought would have worked:

```
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId=**} {
     allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
   }
   match /roles/{roleId=**} {
      function isSuperUser() {
       return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role.isSuperuser == true;
      }
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow write: if isSuperUser();
   }
}
```

I have confirmed the following works, but it's not really that useful...

```
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role != null;
```

If there is a better way to accomplish role base security, I am all ears.

The lack of any debugging tools makes this quite frustrating.

Comment: Basically I am looking for the same thing. I have a "fish" collection, that is owned by a user. Instead of storing the user id, I store a reference to the user. So now, I want to check whether fish.user.id is the same as auth.uid. Is that possible or should I store the userId only?

Comment: had the idea of getting the data directly from the reference as in `request.data.refField.data` but apparently [thats not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446590/firestore-security-rules-with-reference-fields)

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while since the original question but I've had a similar issue and I hope this could help you or others.

Your condition is:
`get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role.isSuperuser == true;`

But `role` is a reference, which (apparently) means you need to `get` it as well. Try this:

`get(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role).data.isSuperuser == true;`

Comment: @JaapWeijland no, unfortunately it didn't. The reference to the other object doesn't seem to be path that I can use to pass to the "get" function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to move the wildcard to a nested path?

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      match /{role=**} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
        allow write: if isSuperUser();
      }
    }
  }
}
```