# Firestore security rules with reference fields

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am a bit stuck here as there is no way to debug those rules. I'd appreciate help with below rules.

I want to access:

`/modules/module-id/sessions/session-id/parts/`

The comparison with `null` in the first part of `hasCompletedPrerequisiteSession()` works well, the second part doesn't!

The path `/modules/moduleId/sessions/sessionId/prerequisite` points to a reference field.

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {

      function hasCompletedPrerequisiteSession(moduleId,sessionId) {
                // this part works well                                   
        return getPrerequisiteSession(moduleId,sessionId) == null ||
           // !!! this part does not work !!!
           hasCompleted(getPrerequisiteSession(moduleId,sessionId).id);
      }

      function getPrerequisiteSession(moduleId,sessionId) {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/modules/$(moduleId)/sessions/$(sessionId)).data.prerequisite;
      }

      function hasCompleted(sessionId) {
        return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/progress/$(request.auth.uid)/sessions/$(sessionId));
      }

      match /modules/{moduleId}/sessions/{sessionId}/parts/{partId} {
        allow read: if hasCompletedPrerequisiteSession(moduleId,sessionId);
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]

(If I store the session ID as a string instead of a reference to the session, it works fine.)

**Edit**

**Questions**

1. **Reference field in security rules.** Assuming `modules/moduleId/owner` points to a field of the type `reference`. What is the proper way to get the id of the referenced document?`get(../modules/moduleId).data.owner.data.id` or `get(../modules/moduleId).data.owner` or something else?

Comment: Thanks @ToniTornado, this didn't work. I've added a question above. Are you able to answer it?

Comment: We need to know your query that is not working to help you. The query is evaluated against security rules before fetching data.

Comment: I want to access `/modules/module-id/sessions/session-id/parts/`. Btw if I store the session id as string instead of a reference to the session, it works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Firebase support:

It seems that in your use case, you want to get the document name (sessionId) from the value of your reference field (prerequisite), unfortunately, **this is not currently supported by Firestore security rules**. I would suggest that you store only the sessionId as String on your `prerequisite` field, or you can also add String field for the `sessionId`. Keep in mind that the exists() and get() functions only allow you to check if a document exists, or retrieve the document at the given path.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that around `getPrerequisiteSession`, after using `get` to pull the object by ref path, you had to use `.data` first before referencing the `id` field. Of course, `id` field needs to be stored as an object field.

For example, in my case I needed to allow user to add a message into a chat only if they're the owner of that chat room. There are 2 "tables" - `chats` and `chat_messages`, and `chat_messages` relate to a specific chat through `chatId` field. `chats` objects have `ownerId` field.
The rule I've used goes like this:

```
    match /chat_messages/{itemId} {
      function isOwner() {
          return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/chats/$(request.resource.data.chatId)).data.ownerId == request.auth.uid;
      }
      
      allow read: if true;
      allow create: if isOwner();
    }
```