# Firestore security rules issues with phone number

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to set some security rules in firebase without luck. Basically I need to check weather the user has been blocked or not based on it's phone number. Here's what I have so far:

```
service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/access/+17777777777);
    }

    match /globals/{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
    }

    match /requests/{document=**} {
      allow write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

If I hard-code the number in the rule itself it does what is supposed to. If I use `$(reqest.auth.token.phone_number)` it does not work.

`allow read, write: if !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/access/$(reqest.auth.token.phone_number));`

I've also tried with `get` as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629170/firestore-security-rule-get-not-work):

```
allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/access/$(reqest.auth.token.phone_number)).blocked == true ||
      get(/databases/$(database)/documents/access/$(reqest.auth.token.phone_number)).data.blocked == true;
```

My data structure looks like this

```
access | +17777777777 | blocked = true
```

I also tried flipping the structure:

```
access | blocked | +17777777777 = true
```

And here is the Authentication payload from the Simulator

```
{
  "uid": "19687a6s87d68as7d968as7d9a8sd",
  "token": {
    "sub": "19687a6s87d68as7d968as7d9a8sd",
    "aud": "my-app",
    "email": "",
    "email_verified": false,
    "phone_number": "+17777777777",
    "name": "",
    "firebase": {
      "sign_in_provider": "google.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem! As per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Path), Paths can also be constructed using the path() function. So you can build your path manually using string concatenation:

```
allow read, write: if exists(path("/databases/" + database + "/documents/access/" + request.auth.token.phone_number));
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in the `$(reqest.auth.token.phone_number)` method. As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50986995/2909074), Firestore unfortunately does not support reference field values in document paths at the moment, which is the reason, why do only the hard-coded values work.

**Edit**

It is strange, but [Firestore's example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) still contradicts my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was very confused. I ended up using UIDs. Somehow they worked ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps, when your authentication is phone authentication, your $uid will be the phone number in international format.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid" : {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null &&  $uid === auth.token.phone_number"
       }
      }
   }
}
```