# Firestore Access Rules that Rely on a Document Reference

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Firestore has a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) type, which is a "pointer" to another firestore document. Using the firebase JavaScript client, you can access properties (e.g. document "id"), directly on the reference.

For example, if there is a document with a `docRef` property that is a firestore DocumentReference:

```
const retrievedDoc = await getFirestoreDocument();
console.log(retrievedDoc.docRef.id); // "jRmSeMYDMKiOPGsmkdaZ"
```

I am trying to accomplish the same thing within firestore rules. There is a [custom function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#custom_functions) named `isOwner`. It uses the firestore rules [`get`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get) call on a document path, and then attempts to access the `docRef.id` just as if it were the JavaScript client above.

```
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/path/to/$(id)).data.docRef.id
```

The value of the document's id is compared against the current user's. But when I test this using the simulator and in real code, it fails. I feel like this should work, but it doesn't.

What *does* work is to store and use the id value directly as a string (e.g. `get(/path/id).docId`) instead of a DocumentReference.

**Should I be able to access the `id` value of a DocumentReference within the firestore rules?** Am I doing something wrong?

I want to avoid doing a second document `get` within the rule as described [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50077247/6193666). That's a second "read" for each trigger of this rule. And I don't think the document id (which is what I need) will be available on the `get` call anyway.

Comment: Isn't `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/path/to/$(id)).docRef.id` just the same `$(id)`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No, the `docRef` property is a DocumentReference to a document elsewhere in Firestore.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The intent is: "If the document reference _here_ points back to _you_, then access granted"

Comment: In that case you're missing a `.data` in there, which is needed to access the fields of a document. Something like `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/path/to/$(id)).data.docRef.id`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents

Comment: I'm sorry @FrankvanPuffelen, that's an error in my question (fixing now). I _do_ have the `.data` in the actual rules file.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I answered below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53601030/5183171) based on documentation, yet I am not able to make it work, thinking of an API issue. Do you work on the API & what could be wrong ? I let you "dive into my brain", thanks

Comment: I've never used references myself, so can't help. Maybe somebody else spots the problem. Btw: since your problem isn't solved, you should probably add the information to the question, and not post it as an answer.

Answer (score 13):

Based on documentation:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource

`get()` method is supposed to returns a Resource object which is supposed to contains a `.id` property (as well as `.data`).

For example, to restrict `write` access to an authenticated user which is the author of a book document (authors documents are identified with the user uid), you would do:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /books/{document=**} {
            allow write: if get(resource.data.authorReference).id == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }

}
```

Yet I'm always having the error `property id is undefined on object` on trying. 
`.data` is accessible so I suppose there is an issue in the api.

Comment: I'm confused. This is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Actually, a reference is a `Path` object in Firestore rules as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Path). So you access the id by the index of the part of the path you need.

In this example I use the incoming document's data which has a reference object to lookup a property on another document from a `get()`

```
match /databases{database}/documents {
   match /contacts/{contact} {

     allow create: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.relatedRules[request.resource.data.relation.path[4]].canBeRelated

     // the [4] assumes the path to be `databases/$(database)/documents/contacts/contactId`
     // your exact index would vary for your data structure
   }
}
```

**First Answer**

**This only works in the Firestore dashboard rules simulator, it is not a working example for either the local emulation or production Firestore.**

This is a year old but I encountered this same puzzling issue, but not on the data from a `get()`, just on the data of the `request.resource.data`. I'm not sure what ought to be available (not even `__name__` is available) in the rules but if you're accessing a resource reference on the data *and* you have a predictable id size (say, 20 characters) you could simply get the range of the `path` on the resource to check against

```
match /databases{database}/documents {
   match /contacts/{contact} {

     allow create: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.relatedRules[request.resource.data.relation.path[9:29]].canBeRelated

     // the [9:29] assumes the path to be `/contacts/20characterLongIdStr`
     // your exact range would vary for your data structure
   }
}
```

Feels like a resource reference object should have at least the id since the path is there. [It appears Firestore won't support this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446590/firestore-security-rules-with-reference-fields) for whatever reason.

Comment: No idea why people up vote the other answer when it is not even an answer.